# Drupal lime survey module configuration

Tags: configuration, drupal-7, drupal-modules, limesurvey

I've run out of ideas for problems 2,3 and 4. [ postimg.org/image/8gy4p25ll ] 
I'm sure i installed the software correctly and put in the right information for the database connections. I also dont know where to find the config.php file that has been mentioned in problem 2.
Need to solve problem 2 to solve 4. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better with some link : https://drupal.org/project/limesurvey_sync

Don't see problem 2,3 or 4 in your post (or any picture, or some explanation).
Better is to explain what you do before !

If you use LimeSurvey 2: config.php are in ./application/config/ directory

Did you install LimeSurvey ?

Comment: i thought the module was all i needed. I installed the lime survey and was able to complete the  configuration. thanks